# How to fix a directed graph on undirected?

Tags: c++, algorithm, path, bellman-ford, shortest

I can not correctly correct the code so that the graph was undirected. By input, by condition, there should be a number of vertices, edges and then a list of adjacent vertices and their weight

```
using namespace std;
const int inf = 10000000;

struct edge {
    int u, v, w;
};

int n, m, v, i;
vector<edge> e;
void solve() {
    vector<int> d(n, inf);
    d[v] = 0;
    for (;;) {
        bool any = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
            if (d[e[j].u] < inf)
                if (d[e[j].v] > d[e[j].u] + e[j].w) {
                    d[e[j].v] = d[e[j].u] + e[j].w;
                    any = true;
                }
        if (!any)  break;
    }
            cout << d[d.size()-1] << endl;
}
int main() {
    cin >> n >> m;
    edge t;
    for (i = 0; i<m; i++)
    {
        cin >> t.u >> t.v >> t.w;
        t.u--; t.v--;
        e.push_back(t);
    }
    solve();
}
```

Comment: It would help if you state what the algorithm is supposed to do and where you are stuck. I'm guessing this is some kind of shortest path? Personally, I dislike single-letter variable names because they make the code extremely hard to read in most cases. A simple fix would be to add the inverse edge as well whenever you read the input edges.

Comment: It is very difficult to understand what your problem is. Also it difficult for people to recreate as you did not provide any sample data. Please refer to [How to create a minimal, recreateable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

From mathematical point of view an undirected graph should be equivalent to a directed one if you substitute every undirected edge with a pair of directed edges with opposite directions.

As far as I can see, you are trying to implement the Bellman-Ford algorithm. Some notes regarding your implementation. As I can see, your `v` global variable is not initialized properly. Is that intentional to assume that the source is the vertex with the index 0? Bellman-Ford finds the shortest paths from the source to all other vertices; you output the length of the path to the vertex with the maximum index, is that what you expect?

One major issue: what would happen if you have a negative cycle (that is possible, as you use signed int for storing the weights)? The benefit of the Bellman-Ford algorithm is that it works correctly if some of the graph's edges have negative weights. Moreover, it allows you to detect the presence of negative cycles, but in your case the algorithm would get into an infinite loop. The solution is to limit the number of iterations with `n`; if on the n-th iteration you find that you still haven't left the loop, there is an negative cycle in your graph.